# Layer group actions (e.g. transparency control)

Tags: qgis, layers, transparency-opacity

I know this question has been asked already... long time ago, though.
When loading a large set of raster data and grouping them in QGIS i miss the opportunity to set basic properties for that group, such as transparency or contrast. Is there a more comfortable way to achieve this functionality apart from using console statements?

Answer (score 4):

There is an existing feature request for this particular functionality. However, it was asked **over 7 years ago** and updated in the last year:

[Group Transparency/Opacity for Legend Groups](https://issues.qgis.org/issues/1898)

---

But there is a [script available](https://github.com/jkall/qgis-processing-scripts/blob/master/set_transparency_for_group.py) which sets the transparency of layers in a group. You can save this script into your `.qgis2/processing/scripts/` path and call it from the *Processing Toolbox*.

Answer (score 1):

This is now possible starting with QGIS 3.24, via "Render Layers as a Group" in the layer styling panel.

[image]

[Changelog for QGIS 3.24 - Feature: Rendering layers as groups](https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog324/index.html#feature-rendering-layers-as-groups)